# JavaScript class definition local scope enable global code completion with tern

Tags: javascript, eclipse, class, scope, code-completion

We use this way to define classes in our js code:

```
  ( function( $, wb ) {
        "use strict";

        /**
        * @class wb.QueryServiceEditor
        * @constructor
        */
        var SELF = wb.QueryServiceEditor = function QueryServiceEditor(
        ) {
        };

        SELF.prototype.fromTextArea = function( selector ){
        };

    }( jQuery, wb ) );
```

The problem I have with this approach is that the code completion I use (eclipse + tern) is not working well with this when using this class QueryServiceEditor from a different scope.

How could we improve our code to make code completion possible everywhere?

Comment: Try to use some jsdoc comments?

Comment: Could you add  the full sample (completion which doesn't work too) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing when you work with ternjs is that you **must declare your variable**. Perhaps you have not declared your **wb** variable?

I have tried with tern.java 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT and it seems it works, here a screenshot with completion for fromTextArea method:

[image]